# Where to properly get _LONGLONG_TYPE defined

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, uint64

I am porting a C/C++ development environment from Solaris 10 to Solaris 11. (Yes, I know - ancient history! Still needed for supporting a legacy product.) Everything has gone smoothly except in the final compilation phase, I am getting `uint64_t` undefined errors. (This is a 32-bit Solaris 11 system.) It is caused by new .h system files being included on S11, not there on S10, which contain these types. I understand that the C99 standard says this should be supported on 32-bit systems, but looking at `int_types.h`, I see that `_LONGLONG_TYPE` needs to be defined to get `uint64_t` defined.

So I tried to include a `-D_LONGLONG_TYPE` in my makefiles, but then I get the compilation error

```
"/usr/include/sys/feature_tests.h", line 394: #error: "No long long in strictly conforming ANSI C & 1990 ISO C environments"
```

So that looks like the wrong track. I scrapped that `-D` option and replaced it with `-D_STDC_C99` (which causes `_LONGLONG_TYPE` to be defined in `feature_tests.h`) and that satisfied the compiler. But is that the correct way to fix this problem?

Comment: What compiler/development environment?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sun Studio 10, Sun C 5.7

Comment: How are you invoking the compiler?  Per [the Sun Studio 10 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/stud.10/819-0494/index.html), it should fully support C99.  And FWIW there is no such thing as a 32-bit Solaris 11 system - 32-bit kernels for SPARC were removed from Solaris 10, and Solaris 11 never supplied 32-bit kernels for either x86 or SPARC CPUs.